# Re-writing pi notation using exponentials

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How might one show that the following is true by re-arranging the term on the left: $$\Pi_{r=0}^{n-1} e^\frac{2ri\pi}{n}=(-1)^{n-1}$$

Comment: Remember in general $\prod\limits _{r}e^{a_r} = e^{\sum\limits_{r} a_r}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\omega_r:=e^{\frac{2\pi ir}{n}}$. Then the $\omega_r$'s, $r=0,\ldots,n-1$ are the $n$ $n^{th}$ roots of unity. That is, they are the solutions of
$$z^n-1=0.$$

Observe that the constant term of the polynomial
$z^n-1=(z-\omega_0)\cdots (z-\omega_{n-1})$
is equal to $-1$ which should be from the product of the constant terms of the linear factors. Thus,
$$(-1)^n\prod_{r=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{2\pi i r}{n}}=\prod_{r=0}^{n-1}(-\omega_r)=-1$$
or dividing both sides by $(-1)^n$, gives
$$\prod_{r=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{2\pi i r}{n}}=-1/(-1)^n=(-1)^{1-n}=(-1)^{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Change the pi notation to a sigma in the exponent. Use the fact that the sum of $r$ from $1$ to $(n-1)$ is $n(n-1)/2$. Cancel out the $2/n$ in the exponent and the answer follows from there. Idk if this is the method you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Re-writing pi notation using exponentials**
\begin{align}
\prod_{r=0}^{n-1} e^{2ri\pi/n} &= \exp\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{2\pi i r}{n}\right)
=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}r\right)
\\
&=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\;\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right)
=e^{\pi i(n-1)}
=\big(e^{\pi i}\big)^{n-1} = (-1)^{n-1}
\end{align}

Comment: How is base e ^{\frac{2\piir}{n}} removed?

Comment: We use Euler's formula $e^{\pi i} = -1$.  Special case of $e^{ti} = \cos t + i \sin t$.

Comment: Apologies, edited. I meant the base e in the first term which is not in the second term.

Comment: Notation $\exp(x)$ means $e^x$.  We use it when $x$ is complicated, to avoid writing things so small they are illegible.

Comment: I mean the base e in e^(2piri/n). Is this because the conversion from Pi to Sigma notation involves a ln operator?

Comment: Or think that the formula is $e^u\;e^v = e^{u+v}$.